# Can I get a list of variables and their types from some python code without running it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope, abstract-syntax-tree, global

I have some python code in a string, which I compile to a code object.

How can I get a list of variable names and types, without running the code (e.g. with AST?) ?

All the variables are in the `global` scope, though it would also may be useful to do similar in certain named functions, e.g. `draw()`.

```
# Example source:
source_code = """
a = 1
b = "hello world"
print(a)
print(b)
"""

code_obj = compile(source_code, "<string>", "exec")

# At this point I would like to know that 'a' is an int and 'b' is a str

exec(code_obj)
```

Comment: Can you run the code and just check the globals() with type()?

Comment: You could use `isinstance()` but then you will have to use some `if else` combination.

Comment: I want to do this before running the code and have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: By "without running the code (e.g. with AST)", do you mean *without AST*, or *without running the code, but with AST*?

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to implement "I have some python code in a string, which I compile to a code object"?

Comment: In general, no. Variables can be created at run-time in response to information (e.g., user input) that simply is not available in the code itself.

Comment: @chepner if variables are created at runtime, then I can skip them.

Comment: @mkrieger1 added example code, hope this helps.

Comment: The documentation of `compile` mentions the `ast.parse` function. Did you try to use that?

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I needed to look at :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be perfect, but it should do what you're after

```py
import ast
class ASTExplorer:
    def __init__(self, source):
        self.tree = ast.parse(source, mode="exec")
        self.result = list()

    class ASTResult:
        def __init__(self, var, expr, vType):
            self.var = var
            self.expression = expr
            self.vType = vType

    def _getLineAssignment(self, lineno):
        return next((node for node in ast.walk(self.tree) if isinstance(node, ast.Name) and node.lineno == lineno), None)

    def getVariables(self):
        for node in ast.walk(self.tree):
            if not isinstance(node, ast.Assign):
                continue
            nodeValue = node.value
            nodeVariable = self._getLineAssignment(node.lineno).id
            if(isinstance(nodeValue, ast.Constant)):
                nodeExpression = node.value.value
                self.result.append(self.ASTResult(nodeVariable, nodeExpression, type(nodeExpression)))
                continue
            elif(isinstance(nodeValue, ast.Call)):
                callFunc = nodeValue.func.id
                callArgs = "(" + (", ".join([str(x.value) for x in nodeValue.args])) + ")"
                self.result.append(self.ASTResult(nodeVariable, f"{callFunc}{callArgs}", ast.Call))
            #elif... other type handling
        return self.result
```

And you would use it like so

```py
source_code = """
myRangeVar = range(1, 10)
myIntVar = 1
myStrVar = "hello world"
myTest = fakeFunct()
myTestTwo = fakeFunct(20)
print(a)
print(b)
"""

explorer = ASTExplorer(source_code)
for result in explorer.getVariables():
    print(f"Found variable '{result.var}' with a value of '{result.expression}' (type: '{result.vType.__name__}')")
```

Which results in

```
Found variable 'myRangeVar' with a value of 'range(1, 10)' (type: 'Call')
Found variable 'myIntVar' with a value of '1' (type: 'int')
Found variable 'myStrVar' with a value of 'hello world' (type: 'str')
Found variable 'myTest' with a value of 'fakeFunct()' (type: 'Call')
Found variable 'myTestTwo' with a value of 'fakeFunct(20)' (type: 'Call')
```

I've added a comment `#elif... other type handling` as this currently only handles declarations of type `Constant` and `Call` but there are other that need to be accounted for if your solution demands it.

Comment: Fantastic, this works + is something I can play with to see how the APIs work.  Will have a play with this, and the docs at https://greentreesnakes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nodes.html#variables that I found after the hint from @mkrieger1

Comment: I will probably modify the version here, once I have a version that fits my use-case, if that's OK ?

Comment: Sure, I wrote it to answer your question, it's yours to use :)